# JS code to chrome extension it's not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a JS code that selects all `<td>` elements and refreshing the page until an element changes to a number.

Unfortunately, after refreshing the page the code ends so I thought to build a chrome extension, but it is so tricky! It does not work! Can you please help me to figure the problem? When I press the button which activates the function, nothing happens.. (console checking)

I just want to achieve a script that will run in the background on a specific tab (not URL). After checking some options, an extension was sounded cool. Maybe there is a better solution?

**manifest.json**

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Grade Refresher!",
"description": "This extension will refresh the page until the grade will shown!",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
 "activeTab"
 ]
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Grade Refhresher</title>
    <script src="refresh.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Grade Refresher</h1>
    <button id="activate">Check this page now!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**refresh.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('activate');

    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

        //my JS code starts here  
        console.log("START");
        //select all td elements
        var table_data = document.querySelectorAll("td");
        var flag = false;
        //td elements 9,19,29.. all with the grades data
        for(var i=9; i<table_data.length && !flag; i+=10){
            console.log('checking '+ table_data[i])
            if(parseInt(table_data[i].innerText) > 0 && parseInt(table_data[i].innerText) < 100){
            window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jmd4OLzhQw0");
            flag = true;
            break;
        } else {
                setInterval(function(){
                console.log("RELOAD PAGE");
                refresh();
                }, 5000);
            }
        }

        function refresh() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Is `refresh.js` running at all? Maybe put a `console.log` _outside_ of the `DOMContentLoaded` handler in case the issue is just that the script tag src is valid.

Comment: popup.html doesn't have access to a web pages `window`, you need to use content-script for that. You also have an `else`, but no `if`

Comment: This question could use a better title.

Comment: I've tried to put `console.log` outside the `DOMContentLoaded`. I don't see it on the site (Inspect window) that I want to activate.. but I can see it when I do Inspect on the activate button.. (`<button id="activate">Check this page now!</button>`)